# How can I get an older version of openjdk-17 from apt on termux?

Tags: android, package, apt, java-17, termux

I have been trying to use advanced package tool to install openjdk-17 on an android device using termux. However, this always results in the package manager installing an "internal" version of java 17.0.6a, which is not usable to me.

I have already tried using "apt list -a openjdk-17" to try and find older versions, but there is only one version available, which isn't marked as internal but installing it still gives me the internal build.